# Add an item to a list in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I am trying to add an item to a list in Prolog like this.

```
safe_square(Xa, Ya, X, Y) :-
   append([X], [Y], Path),
   path(Path).

path(Path) :-
    append(Path, _, NewPath),
    write(NewPath).
```

This method is not working.

Comment: You need to explain some things. *This method is not working* doesn't mean much without explaining what your main query is that you called (with an example), what you are getting for results (specifically), and what results you were expecting. `append([X], [Y], Path)` just results in `Path` being `[X, Y]`. `append(Path, _, newPath)` appends an anonymous variable to `Path`.

Comment: @lurker the results overrides the final path, so the path will be X,Y and then the newPath should have all values that have been sent down e.g. 4,1, then 4,2 will be display if they are sent in that order but it is only displaying 4,2 as it was the last to be displayed.

Comment: @GuinnessIsLife `append(Path, _, newPath)` if `Path = [X, Y]` will result in, `newPath = [X, Y | _]`. In other words, a path with `X` and `Y` as the first two elements and an anonymous variable tail.